# Download Office 2016 through HUP

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I bought microsoft office 2016 through home use program, but I don't have access to it other than an old download link. That old download link is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I bough Microsoft Office 2016 through home use program, but I don't
>   have access to it other than an old download link. That old download
>   link is not working.

You can use the [Virtual Support Agent (English only)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contact/virtual-agent/?partnerId=office&flowId=office-content&userInput=I%20need%20to%20download%20office%20using%20my%20product%20key) and it will provide you a link.

> You can use a [Virtual Support Agent (English only)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contact/virtual-agent/?partnerId=office&flowId=office-content&userInput=I%20need%20to%20download%20office%20using%20my%20product%20key) to receive a link
>   to download and reinstall the products listed above. Just enter your
>   product key when prompted by the Virtual Support Agent (English only).
>   After the product is installed, you'll need to activate it using the
>   product key.

Source: **My Email**

If you do not have the product key then, you can retrieve it, provided you have access to the original email account.  **If you do not have access to the associated email account then you are out of luck.**

> If you previously purchased Office, Visio, or Project, please go to
>   the [Order History](http://If%20you%20previously%20purchased%20Office,%20Visio,%20or%20Project,%20please%20go%20to%20the%20Order%20History%20page%20to%20have%20your%20product%20key(s)%20emailed%20to%20you.%20To%20do%20so,%20you%20will%20need%20to%20have%20access%20to%20the%20email%20address%20you%20used%20to%20make%20the%20purchase.) page to have your product key(s) emailed to you. To
>   do so, you will need to have access to the email address you used to
>   make the purchase.

Source: [Home Use Program - FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/home-use-program/frequently-asked-questions)